# How to read the ZipEntry CRC from a nested archive (zip in zip)

Tags: java, zip

**See comments of selected answer, the issue was with my test data and not the code.**

I'm trying to read the CRCs of a Zip archive using the ZipEntry object. This works for zips directly on the file system.

```
zStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipPath))
zEntry = zStream.getNextEntry()
zEntry.getCrc()
```

I want to get the CRC from a nested zipEntry, but I always returns -1

```
zStream = new ZipInputStream(new ZipFile(zipPath).getInputStream(zEntry))
zStream.getNextEntry().getCrc()
// always equal -1
```

Is there a way to read the CRC without extracting the nested zip to the FS? Why doesn't it work as is?

Comment: Which `zEntry` are you using in your second example?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the zEntry of the nested zip

Comment: Maybe I'm slow today, but I'd like to see the zip structure you're trying to extract from and which CRC you are trying to read.

Answer (score 1):

> zStream = new ZipInputStream(new ZipFile(zipPath).getInputStream(zEntry))

That won't work. Try this:

```
ZipInputStream innerZip = new ZipInputStream(zStream);
```

after you've got to the (outer) `ZEntry` concerned, then iterate `innerZip`'s own ZEntries and get their CRCs etc, whatever you want.

Comment: The nested CRCs still return -1, plus closing the inner stream also affects the outer stream.

Comment: So don't close it then. Maybe there are no CRCs on the nested entries?

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. I looked at the nested entry (a signed jar) and it appears that the jarsigner is stripping the CRCs from the archive.

Answer (score 0):

If reading one entry after another, the implementation of java.util.zip.ZipInputStream does not deliver the CRC of the current entry. It is available (for the previous entry) only after calling getNextEntry() again!

AFAIK this is not documented but urgently needs to.

Answer (score -1):

This really appears to be a bug/limitation of the ZipEntry interface. There should be an API to calculate the CRC.

Here is some Groovy code to generate a missing CRC:

```
long calculateCRC( zStream) {
    def crc32 = new CRC32()
    crc32.update( IOUtils.toByteArray(zStream))
    return crc32.value
}
```

Comment: Why? It's pointless unless there is a CRC in the zip file to compare it to. Not a bug. Not a limitation.

Comment: So you agree ZipEntry CRC is not usefull unless you manually generate the CRC. I still think the Java Zip API should provide this feature instead of forcing everyone to roll there own CRC check.